# Hadoop 2.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit Library

Tags: java, hadoop, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 (32 Bit) and tried to install the Apache Hadoop 2.4 version but whenever i try to start the services i am getting the following error 
 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
I tried all solutions for re-compiling the native libraries but those all are solutions for 64 bit OS.
I am getting frustrated why this is happening and when i run the $ jps command it shows only NameNode running .. 
Can any please help me out on this.

Comment: Keep in mind this is only a warning and the cluster should work just fine even with this warning. It simply means that the C++ native optimized code will not be used. It will use Java for those implementation instead. I am running the same configuration for 32 bit ubuntu and do not have this problem btw.

Comment: @ChrisHinshaw can u give me the link for the tutorial which u used for the configuration or can u provide me the steps to set up the hadoop on the 32 bit ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run this to help you identify what libraries you are missing.

```
${HADOOP_BIN}/hadoop checknative
```

This will give you something like the following.

```
chris@chris:/opt/hadoop/apps/hadoop$ ./bin/hadoop checknative
14/07/07 08:56:25 WARN bzip2.Bzip2Factory: Failed to load/initialize native-bzip2 library system-native, will use pure-Java version
14/07/07 08:56:25 INFO zlib.ZlibFactory: Successfully loaded & initialized native-zlib library
Native library checking:
hadoop: true /opt/hadoop/apps/versions/hadoop-2.4.0/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0
zlib:   true /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
snappy: false 
lz4:    true revision:99
bzip2:  false
```

Comment: Thanks and I will try to run this command and will tell what is the output of this.

Comment: I got the same output as u said .. but how to make the all nodes running in hadoop .. please help me on this ..